# How to draw a T-frame?

Tags: math-mode

How can I  re-produce the following figure using LaTeX? (Drawn in excel, using borders).

[image]

Comment: ...the fonts look more like TeX's Computer Modern than what Excel would provide.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can either use an `array` in math mode:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{array}{r|l}
    \text{Independent Variable} & \text{Dependent Variable} \\ \hline
    x_1 & y_1 \\
    x_2 & y_2 \\
    \vdots & \vdots \\
    x_n & y_n
  \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

or you could do something similar using a text mode `tabular`. [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) provides `\text{<stuff>}` that typesets `<stuff>` in text mode within math mode. If you're interested in centering the `\vdots` with respect to the other elements in the column, you could use the [`calc` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/calc) which provides `\widthof{<stuff>}`. Here's a brief example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\usepackage{calc}% http://ctan.org/pkg/calc
\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{array}{r|l}
    \text{Independent Variable} & \text{Dependent Variable} \\ \hline
    x_1 & y_1 \\
    x_2 & y_2 \\
    \makebox[\widthof{$x_2$}][c]{$\vdots$} & \makebox[\widthof{$y_2$}][c]{$\vdots$} \\
    x_n & y_n
  \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

The use of `\vdots` provides a slightly different view to yours. However, if may be accomplished using three identical rows of `\cdot & \cdot \\` replacing the `\vdots & \vdots \\`:

[image]

Comment: IMHO the compact version with vdots is to be preferred. Also to center them a bit  `$\,\vdots\,\,$`, what do you think?

Comment: @YiannisLazarides: Thanks, I included something to this effect in my revised answer. I agree on the use of `\vdots` as opposed to three `\cdot`s.